# Import tables from Bigtable - Google CLoud

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I have exported a few tables from Google Bigtable and imported them following the steps provided by Gcloud, However, after importing it doesn't look like the tables are being imported

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As it stands, your question is light on details, making it hard to answer.  What specific steps did you take to export tables from BigTable to GCloud?  What results do you observe which indicate the import wasn't successful?  As a start, consider editing your question to provide answers to the above questions.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to follow the **[Exporting](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/exporting-sequence-files#bigtable) and [Importing](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/importing-sequence-files#import-table) a table from Cloud Bigtable instructions** as well as verify you are replacing all the values in brackets from the java commands with the appropriate values of your project.

Additionally, you can use the `cbt -instance [INSTANCE_ID] count [TABLE_NAME]` command in order to print the total number of rows in the table; in this way, you will be able to verify that the table is being imported correctly. Take a look on the [cbt Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference) GCP documentation to know more about this tool functionality.